# Getting Too many requests error when trying to fetch data from API on NodeJS backend, but works on React frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from `https://api.solscan.io/chaininfo` using a NodeJS backend application, but I am getting `429: Too many requests` error.

The interesting thing is that the same API works perfectly fine on a React frontend application using either `fetch` or `axios`.

I have tested some other approaches including `curl` on Windows and even fetching the API from a web browser (Chrome on Windows), and they all work as expected.

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   Methods   |  Environment   |        Result         |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| fetch       | React Frontend | Works                 |
| axios       | React Frontend | Works                 |
| curl        | Windows        | Works                 |
| Web Browser | Chrome Windows | Works                 |
| fetch       | NodeJS Backend | 429 Too many requests |
| axios       | NodeJS Backend | 429 Too many requests |
| Postman     | Windows        | 429 Too many requests |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Here's the code I am using to fetch the API on NodeJS: (referencing the `axios` approach)

```js
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get("https://api.solscan.io/chaininfo")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I have also created a CodeSandbox project with the exact same code in case you want to test it yourself: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-morse-symc4p?file=%2Findex.js%3A6%2C32

What could be causing this discrepancy between the NodeJS backend and React frontend, and how can I fix it to make it work on the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the API you are trying to access checks for something you would have on a browser request. After playing a bit with the API, I found that adding a User-Agent header does the trick:

```
const axios = require("axios");

axios
  .get("https://api.solscan.io/chaininfo", {
       headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.error(error.response.status)
    console.error(error.response.statusText);
  });
```